# CakePHP $this->Auth->login() issues

Tags: cakephp

I am using a custom function to log in a user, where he/she posts their email and password to a function login2() and that function authenticates the user as:

```
$this->Auth->login()
```

My understanding is this should be sufficient to automatically log in the user, right? However I am noticing strange behavior where sometimes it works and sometimes it does not for the same credentials.

Comment: does it spit out error "Login failed"? Or it just resets the page, or redirect somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to make a "login2" method, if you set `$this->Auth->autoRedirect = false` it will try a normal login, and then run the logic in your login action.  I have done a similiar thing to allow username or email login, please see my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965492/using-username-instead-of-email-in-cakephps-auth-component/6965695#6965695).