# Login with email address or username in CakePHP v2.0

Tags: php, cakephp

In CakePHP prior to 2.0 you could allow a user to login using their email address by stopping the autoRedirect and then comparing the username data to the email column in your database (apparently Cake could then fallback to username checks if not an email).

In CakePHP 2.0 this has changed and you login manually using `$this->Auth->login()`

My question is how do I get this working for 2.0? I have some quite complicated code that does a variety of things such as handle ajax and postback requests, locking of accounts if a user tries to login too many times etc so it's quite long!

As you will see I check if the account actually exists manually so I can show a message of account not found before going through the authentication process if the case, and also use this to lock the account of that user if 5 fail attempts.

The main problem here is allowing the system to check on both usernames and email addresses for authentication, the system in place does LOCK the user if you use the email address as it handles that in the mentioned check, but it will always fail because the authentication cannot handle it.

Hope someone can help, offer ideas tips. Thanks

```
if ($this->request->is('post'))
        {       
            $opts = array(
               'conditions'=>array(
                   'OR'=>array(
                      'User.username'=>$this->data['User']['username'],
                      'User.email'=>$this->data['User']['username']
                    )
                )
            );

            $user = $this->User->find('first', $opts);

            if(!empty($user))
            {
                if($user['User']['status'] == 0)
                {
                    if($this->request->is('ajax'))
                    {
                        $this->autoRender = false;
                        echo json_encode(array('authenticated'=>false,'error'=>__('Sorry your account is currently locked. Please reset your password.?')));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Sorry your account is currently locked. Please reset your password.'), 'default', array(), 'auth');
                    }
                }
                else
                {   
                    if ($this->Auth->login())
                    {   
                        if ($this->request->is('ajax'))
                        {   
                            $this->autoRender = false;
                            if(isset($this->params['url']['continue']))
                            {
                                $pathtoredirect = $this->UrlEncode->base64url_decode($this->params['url']['continue']);

                                echo json_encode(array('authenticated'=>true,'redirect'=>$pathtoredirect,'base'=>false));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $pathtoredirect = $this->Auth->redirect();

                                echo json_encode(array('authenticated'=>true,'redirect'=>$pathtoredirect,'base'=>true));
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if(isset($this->params['url']['continue']))
                            {
                                $pathtoredirect = $this->UrlEncode->base64url_decode($this->params['url']['continue']);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $pathtoredirect = $this->Auth->redirect();
                            }
                            return $this->redirect($pathtoredirect);
                        }               
                    }
                    else
                    {               
                        if($this->Session->read('attempts'))
                        {
                            $attempts = $this->Session->read('attempts') + 1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $attempts = 1;
                        }

                        $this->Session->write('attempts', $attempts);

                        if($attempts >= 5)
                        {
                            $this->User->id = $user['User']['id'];
                            $this->User->saveField('status', 0);
                            if ($this->request->is('ajax'))
                            {
                                $this->autoRender = false;
                                echo json_encode(array('authenticated'=>false,'error'=>__('Username or password is incorrect. For security reasons this account has now been locked and you must reset your password to unlock it.')));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Username or password is incorrect. For security reasons this account has now been locked and you must reset your password to unlock it.'), 'default', array(), 'auth');
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if ($this->request->is('ajax'))
                            {
                                $this->autoRender = false;
                                echo json_encode(array('authenticated'=>false,'error'=>__('Username or password is incorrect')));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Username or password is incorrect'), 'default', array(), 'auth');
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if ($this->request->is('ajax'))
                {
                    $this->autoRender = false;
                    echo json_encode(array('authenticated'=>false,'error'=>__('Sorry that account does not exist.')));
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Sorry that account does not exist.'), 'default', array(), 'auth');
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Instead of querying the database for either username = userInput OR email = userInput why not use regex to determine if the string they've entered is a valid email address, check email if it does, username if it doesn't.

Comment: Yeah but how do I do this using `$this->Auth->login()` in 2.0?

Comment: So - long question short, you want the user to be able to login with a single field, but you want to check it against both the username field and the email field using Cake's Auth Component - right?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if the AuthComponent can be configured to check for two fields automatically, but here is an alternative:

```
/*
* AppController
*/
beforeFilter()
{
    $this->Auth->authenticate = array('Form' => array('fields' => array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password')));
}

/*
* UsersController
*/
function login()
{
  if($this->request->is('post'))
  {
    $logged_in = false;

    if($this->Auth->login())
    {
      $logged_in = true;
    }
    else
    {
      $this->Auth->authenticate = array('Form' => array('fields' => array('username' => 'username', 'password' => 'password')));
      $this->Auth->constructAuthenticate();

      $this->request->data['User']['username'] = $this->request->data['User']['email']; 

      if($this->Auth->login())
      {
          $logged_in = true;
      }
    }

    if($logged_in)
    {
      /*
       * Do what you want here
       */
    }
    else
    {
      /*
       * Do what you want here
       */
    }
  }
}
```

Then of course if you want to be able to perform only one test to check for both fields, you could move this code into a Component instead of calling the `$this->Auth->login()` method directly.

Comment: If you are declaring that username = email does Cake automatically fall back to search for a user with the username instead?

Comment: I don't think so, and that's why I call `$this->Auth->login()` again after having changed its configuration.

Comment: Hmm that seems very sloppy. This was dead easy to do in CakePHP 1.3 so I'm not sure why it's so hard in 2.0 :(

Comment: How did you use to do it in Cake 1.3. I just looked at the code of 1.3 and didn't see any automatic fallback to another field than the one you specify for the username. And actually I would have found this weird if Cake would have automatically searched in another field without being asked it to do so ! After a bit of research I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965492/using-username-instead-of-email-in-cakephps-auth-component which seems to be based on the same principle. Moreover, the code I gave you is not so complicated.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean that Cake 1.3 handled it by default. What you did was stop autoRedirect and then do something very similar to what you did in terms of saying username = email and then it would try and do that first and then fallback to the Auth defaults if it didn't find a user. The reason I find your code more sloppy (I don't mean that personally rather just the way Cake is struggling) is because we are checking the login twice rather than saying can you find either an email or username that matches with the password in one swoop.

Comment: The thing that has really changed is the fact that the first call to `login()` is not done automatically anymore by the AuthComponent. So in your case, you have to do it twice where you probably used to make it once. In the same way that people that used to implement login with the automatic call only have now to call it once. But on the other side authentication is now more flexible and all in all, I think it makes sense. And if you absolutely want to have a function that check for both fields, you could write a Component or probably better, a custom authentication class.

Comment: I still can't get this working though. I have combined your code with mine but I can only login using the username. The email address always shows the error that they are incorrect details. And I have done the code in the AppController to say to use the email over the username. Any ideas why this does not work in version 2.0?

Comment: See here and I'm using bare essential code and I still can't login using the email address: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908489/authenticating-with-email-address-in-cakephp-v2-0