# Cakephp 2 app insists on trying to authenticate with username, instead of email

Tags: php, cakephp, model

I have an app recently upgraded from cakephp 1.3 to cakephp 2. When trying to log in, it insists on checking the db for a 'Customer.username' field equal to the email, but I'm pretty sure I configured it to use email.

Heres my AppController:

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    public $components = array('Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array('username' => 'Email', 'password' => 'password')
            )
        )
    ), 'Security', 'AntiXss', 'Cookie');

    public $helpers = array('Js', 'Html', 'Form', 'Number', 'DateFormat', 'Currency', 'Session', 'DebugKit.Toolbar');
    public $uses = array('Language', 'Customer', 'Affiliate', 'Setting', 'Whitelabel');

    public function beforeFilter() {
        Debugger::dump($this);
        //Configure AuthComponent
        $this->Auth->userModel = 'Customer';
        $this->Auth->fields = array('username' => 'Email', 'password' => 'password');
        $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'customers', 'action' => 'login');
        $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'customers', 'action' => 'login');
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = '/';
        $this->Auth->identifyMethod = 'login_identify';
        $this->Auth->authError = __("Please log in to continue.");
        $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
        AuthComponent::ALL => array('userModel' => 'Customer'),
            'Basic',
            'Form' => array('fields' => array('username' => 'Email'))
        );
```

And then the login code in the View:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Customer', array('action' => 'login')); ?>
<fieldset class="Login">
    <?php
    echo $this->Form->input('Email', array("label"=>__('Email')));
    echo $this->Form->input('password', array("label"=>__('Password')));
    echo $this->whiteLabelElement('login_terms');
    echo $this->Form->button(__('Log In'), array('type'=>'submit', 'class' => 'button loginButton'));
    ?>
</fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

And the login code from the Customers Controller:

```
function login() {
    if($this->loggedCustomerData) { $this->redirect("/"); } // If user is logged in, redirect to home
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect('/accounts/'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Username or password is incorrect'), 'default', array(), 'auth');
        }
    }
}


// This is not an action. It's called by the login process, passing in email and password, for this method to return
//   the customer that should be logged in (or null if invalid password). Here, we resolve to the right customer record
//   in the right whitelabel
function login_identify($data, $conditions) {
    if (isset($data['id'])) { // This means we got called by AutoLogin...
        $this->LoginAudit->LogLogin($data['id'], "auto_login");
        return array('Customer' => $data); // Somehow we get a Customer array, but not in a sub-array.
    }

    $whitelabel = $this->Whitelabel->GetWhitelabelFromHost();
    $email = $data['Customer.Email'];

    // First look for a *customer* (not a lead) in this whitelabel
    $objCustomer = $this->Customer->findByWhitelabelAndEmail($whitelabel, $email, false, false);

    // Then, a *customer* in another sharing whitelabel
    if (!$objCustomer) { $objCustomer = $this->Customer->findByWhitelabelAndEmail($whitelabel, $email, true, false); }

    // Finally, if there are no customers we can use, maybe we have a lead in this whitelabel
    // We don't look for leads in other whitelabels, that makes no sense. The customer can register in this site at this point, but he can't login
    if (!$objCustomer) { $objCustomer = $this->Customer->findByWhitelabelAndEmail($whitelabel, $email, false, true); }

    // Finally, validate the password if we found a customer
    if ($objCustomer) {
        if ($data['Customer.password'] == $objCustomer['Customer']['password']) {
            $this->LoginAudit->LogLogin($objCustomer['Customer']['id']);
            return $objCustomer;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Did you see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908489/authenticating-with-email-address-in-cakephp-v2-0?rq=1) post? It seems to be the same problem to me.

Comment: is the name of you colume in db is **E**mail or **e**mail

Answer (score 0):

FROM: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authetication.html

```
To configure different fields for user in $components array:

// Pass settings in $components array
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array('username' => 'email')
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, Is exactly than your question.

Comment: I have that in my code though, and it still insists on looking for a username field.

Comment: yes, I'm sorry. Is the same code... where is the identifyMethod "login_identify"??
$this->Auth->identifyMethod = 'login_identify';

Comment: Its in the customers controller, Ill add the code to the edit

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think this method does not work in cake2. In cake 2 you can create your own authentication class, extending the base auth class.
Look at: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html
Section "Creating Custom Authentication objects"

Good luck.